# Kotlin equals (==) sign not recognized

Tags: java, kotlin

I have very strange behavior when using Kotlin class.

I have those simple classes :

`ClassA` class:

```
@Entity
class ClassA() : AbstractAuditable<Long>()
```

`AbstractAuditable` class

```
open class AbstractAuditable<T : Serializable> : AbstractPersistable<T>() {


//    @Suppress("RedundantOverride")
//    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
//        return super.equals(other)
//    }

}
```

`AbstractPersistable`  **JAVA** class has this equals method overridden

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {

}
```

Strange thing is that when I try to use equals operator `==`
it can not be resolved.

[image]

**Observation I**:   When I uncomment `AbstractAuditable`s equals method everything works.

**Observation II**:   As  the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html) says `==` sign searches for `equals(Any?)` method. and in this case, it is not able to find it because only `equals` method in parent hierarchy is `AbstractPersistable`s `equals(Object)` method.

**Observation III**:  Using `===` works.

**Observation IV**:  It is not the IntelliJ issue. Command-line build gives the same results

Why is Kotlin not able to use `equals(Object)` method from java class as `equals(Any?)` equivalent?

Comment: Will the error go away if you fix the error in `val old : ClassA? = ClassA()` line first? I can't reproduce your problem on `1.3.71`.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki No, I changed the code little bit for the question.  I have removed constructor parameters for simplicity

Comment: What about @Entity? Is there any code generation related to this annotation?

Comment: I am using 1.3.70 right now

Comment: @Mike Yes actually. This is a Spring Boot project with JPA and hibernate

Comment: Hm... switching Kotlin versions from 1.3.70 to 1.3.71  back and forth fixed it. It must have been cache issue some kind. Thanks for the help.